# Where the assert message will be displayed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, assert

I tried the code

```
package Base;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Assertcheck 
{
    @Test
    public void check() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true, "testing the string true");
    }
}
```

and the code succeeds but the message "testing the string true" is not displayed. i checked in console output and also in testNG results.

Comment: Check this thread and see if it helps.
`https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/KPICr9XhP1w`

Answer (score 1):

Refer the site for more info:
http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue(java.lang.String, boolean)

```
public static void assertTrue(java.lang.String message, boolean condition)
```

Asserts that a condition is true. If it isn't it throws an AssertionError with the given message.
Parameters:
`message` - the identifying message for the AssertionError (null okay)

`condition` - condition to be checked

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information, Message parameter will get executed only if the Assert condition get false. The message will appear in console.

But in case Assert condition passed, the message part will not get executed, so you will not see any message in that case.

If you want to see the message in both the cases, you should use try-catch statement like

```
try{
     Assert.assertTrue(true, "testing the string true");
     //print your message for the case assert pass and/or perform any other event
}catch (Exception e){
     //print your message for the case assert fails and/or perform any other event
     loggerObj.debug("Assert Failed "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you and i am using log4j. now could you tell me how to print this message in it only if the condition fails or suggest me any material for this

Comment: @Lucan :- I have updated the code for your answer, check the catch statement.

Comment: Hope you have created the log4j.properties file for this.

Comment: I am using keyword hybrid framework and am asserting some values and even-though the assert fails the testng says it succeeds. how to solve this?

Comment: @Lucan: When you are using TestNG, do not use try catch for Assert statements. In that case, if Assert fails, TestNG will show the error. Basically what happens in your case, if Assert failed, it throw an exception and this exception is handled by the catch statement, so in both case whether exception occurs or not, you have a defined rule. So for testNG both become expected. Remove the try-Catch statement and let me know its working or not.

Comment: try catch is not the appropriate solution for the above question

Answer (score -2):

If the condition fails then,  the comment It must reflect the   in testng logs,
check "Results of running class" tab of testng at bottom
it will be there if the condition is not true.

Comment: Hi, since this is a very old question, please edit your answer to explain what it provides that the existing answers don't. Thanks.